# Background color slider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background colour slider. Almost like an automatic image slider that changes the image every 5 seconds, but with colours instead of images. The background should transition from yellow, to blue, to red.

This is the closest I can get, but it fades the colours. I want the colours to transition statically. Colour to colour like with an image slider.

```css
div {
  animation: bgColor 10s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
@keyframes bgColor {
  33.33% {
    background-color: #ffc60b;
  }
  66.66% {
    background-color: #90a0d6;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #ff6666;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `@keyframes bgColor {
  
  0%,50%{
    background: yellow;
  }
  51%,100%{
    background: red;
  }
  
}` do this way to remove the transition of background

Comment: Please post this as an answer

Comment: i changed the size of the div because i think its more evident like this but of course you can change it back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you set the animation duration for the AnimateCSS library in :root (5 seconds).

Then you load the AnimateCSS library via the CDN.

Finally you need to specify a z-index for each div box that is always higher than the previous box so that it shows "over" the previous color.

Also adjust the animation-delays accordingly to your parameters.

```css
:root {
  --animate-duration: 5000ms;
}

.c {
  position:absolute;width:250px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;
}

.box {
  min-width:250px;width:250px;height:200px;position:absolute;
}

.div1 {
  background:blue;
}
.div2{background:purple;z-index:5;animation-delay:5s;}
.div3{background:green;z-index:10;animation-delay:10s;}
```

```html
<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
</head>
<div class="c">
  <div class="box div1 animate__animated animate__slideInLeft"></div>
    <div class="box div2 animate__animated animate__slideInLeft"></div>
   <div class="box div3 animate__animated animate__slideInLeft"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: This is correct! Can you add the slider effect? The transition should be that it slides across to the left and the new background colour appears. @LaurentC

Comment: sure give me 2-3 minute ill be right back and update

Comment: Sure! Thank you @LaurentC

Comment: ok im avail sorry for the delay do you still need this ill update the answer

Comment: Yes, I do. @LaurentC

Comment: If you could, that would be great.

Comment: yes im just trying a way just css i have a tendency to use js for that lol

Comment: You can use javascript if you need! @LaurentC

Comment: @asohasf1241 ok good im almost done only one little glitch i have to fix. i ended up using AnimateCSS too lol. so complicated for a simple anim. see the codepen here all thats missing is the green slide https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/eYzJWoV

Comment: Great! It should show 3 different colours, each for 5 seconds, then do the loop again. You are more than welcome to use javascript @LaurentC

Comment: yeah ok 3 colors 5 seconds. you want infinite loop or just one time?

Comment: if you other animations they are listed here https://animate.style/

Comment: Thank you so much! What can I add to this to make it an infinite loop? @LaurentC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223069/discussion-between-asohasf1241-and-laurentc).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the transition  you can do

```
div {
  animation: bgColor 10s forwards;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
@keyframes bgColor {
  
  0%,33%{
    background: #ffc60b;
  }
  33.1%,66.66%{
    background: #90a0d6;
  }
  66.67%,100%{
    background: #ff6666;
  }
  
}
```

I added forward at animation so that it stuck when animation finishes and javascript you can do

```
let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.style.background = '#ffc60b'

setTimeout(()=> div.style.background = '#90a0d6', 10000/3)
setTimeout(()=> div.style.background = '#ff6666', 10000)
```